# HTML5 Geolocation and Audio in Eclipse internal web browser

Tags: eclipse, html, geolocation, html5-audio

I am trying to show audio and google map in a simple HTML5 page. When I run it in other outside browsers like Chrome, Mozilla everything works perfectly.

But same is not working in my eclipse internal web browser and I want the output in that only.

Here is my project link on GitHub:
https://github.com/Venkatesh-Devale/cmpe273/tree/master/StaticRefresher

Please help me know why this is so?

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#divVideo, #divAudio {
 
 width:40%;
}


#divMyHeader {
 background-color:orange;

}

#map {
        height: 400px;
        overflow: auto !important; 
}

html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>About Me</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hello.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="divMainPage">
 <div id="divMyHeader">
  <h1>Venkatesh Devale</h1>
  <h6>SJSU ID: 012420148</h6>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
 <p> 
  I am creating this page to introduce me as we all are pretty new,
  through this refresher assignment. 
  Below is my short video which will tell you about myself.
 </p>
 <div id="divVideo">
  <video controls>
   <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
 </div>
 <p>
  Below is my favorite songs audio. Please guess it.
 </p>
 <div id="divAudio">
  <audio controls>
   <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="divFeedbackShowingInputTypes" style="border-style:groove;">
 <form>
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td>First Name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="txtFirstName" autofocus></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last Name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="txtLastName"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Email:</td>
   <td><input type="email" name="email" title="<any characters>@<your mail account>.com" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+[@][a-zA-Z]+[.com]" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Telephone:</td>
   <td><input type="tel" name="phone" title="XXX-XXX-XXXX" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>
 
 </form>
 </div>
 <div id="myGeoLocatioWithMap">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
var myMap, myLocationPanel;

function getFirstMap() {
   myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -58.397, lng: 197.644},
    zoom: 7
   });

   myLocationPanel = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

   if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log("Geolocation is available");
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMyPosition, findLocationNotFoundError);
   } else {
     handleLocationError(false, myLocationPanel, myMap.getCenter());
   }
}

function showMyPosition(position) {
 console.log("Geolocation is available");
 var myPosition = {
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
 };
 
 myLocationPanel.setPosition(myPosition);
 myLocationPanel.setContent("Your location is here");
 myLocationPanel.open(myMap);
 myMap.setCenter(myPosition);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myPosition,
  map: myMap
 });
}

function findLocationNotFoundError() {
 showLocationError(true, myLocationPanel, myMap.getCenter());
}

function showLocationError(checkDoesBrowserHasLocation, myLocationPanel, mapCenter) {
   myLocationPanel.setPosition(mapCenter);
   if(checkDoesBrowserHasLocation) {
    myLocationPanel.setContent('Somehow geolocation service is not working, we are fixing it');
   } else {
    myLocationPanel.setContent('Seems that the browser does not support the geolocation');
   }
   myLocationPanel.open(myMap);
}
 </script>
 
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBd-SiW0EEjuidG6nhM6iSeDt9epJPvYno&callback=getFirstMap">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to post your code here. [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: Thank you!..I have addedthe code snippets.